# PHP else Statement

Tags: php

The first part of this code works fine, I just can't seem to get the `else` statment working for when `if ($row[password] == $password_hash)` is `false`. I'm sure I only have a small error somewhere but just can't seem to find it.

```
list ($sessionname) = checkuser();
if (isset($_POST['save'])){

connect();

$currentpass = sha1($_POST['password']);
$newpass = sha1($_POST['password1']);

$sql = "SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = '$sessionname'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($row['password'] == $currentpass)

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password = '$newpass' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
            $updated = "Your password has been updated";
               print_r($row);
        }else{
    $a = "Passwords do not match";
    return $b;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: What error, if any do you get? Also, echo out your SQL statements and display MySQL errors.

Comment: Indent your code properly for better readability :)

Comment: You must get at least one "undefined index" notice. If you don't, you need to configure your PHP installation to display errors.

Comment: no matter what i input it always returns "your password has been updated"

Comment: If you start to indent your code correctly, you will notice your problem pretty fast. As @Herbert stated in his answer, you are missing the opening curly brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an opening curly brace after the `if` statement.

```
if ($row['password'] == $currentpass) {
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password = '$newpass' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
    $updated = "Your password has been updated";
    print_r($row);
}else{
    $a = "Passwords do not match";
    return $b;
}
```

Notice the { after `if ($row['password'] == $currentpass)`

Without the brace (and no error reporting) it's skipping the query and showing the string “Your password has been updated”. That’s why the password doesn’t change in the database and why nothing else seems to work.

By the way:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

will turn on error reporting

Comment: thanks works perfectly. i noticed around 20mins after posting this.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure** MySQL is **returning a result set**, by using `print_r($row);` to debug code.

```
if ($row['password'] == $password_hash){
```

Hint: You should use quotes around string keys. If you leave out the quotes, PHP thinks it's a constant.

Read: ["why is `$foo[bar]` wrong".](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: PHP cares, believe me. It was just a friendly hint, not a solution. The real soluton is one below.

Comment: I just gave you a link proving otherwise. PHP converts bare strings into a string.

Comment: @NullUserException : PHP cares for quotes.

Comment: "You don't have to quote single-word strings. For instance, $age['Fred'] is the same as $age[Fred]. However, it's considered good PHP style to always use quotes, because quoteless keys are indistinguishable from constants. When you use a constant as an unquoted index, PHP uses the value of the constant as the index." ([source](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html))

Comment: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant x - assumed 'x' in php shell code on line 1 --
This means PHP cares. Sorry. It might not look so to an average programer. I also said it is **not my solution**, just a side note that will make OP nicer programmer.

Comment: @NullUserException Just because it works does not mean you should use it that way. It WILL raise an error and it is NOT recommended ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)).

Comment: @NullUserException: I never said it was. I'm saying this third time in the row. Please read more carefully. Also thanks for providing a link into my answer.

Comment: @Rok: Then this should have been a comment. It is not an answer.

Comment: The OP said `no matter what i input it always returns "your password has been updated"`; there is a resultset being returned.

Comment: User posted that 16 mins ago, I answered 20 mins ago, smartass. Thanks for -1.

Comment: i've added the print_r($row); and its showing my passwords as being the same no matter what i type in. Now im confused. Code updated above.

Comment: That means problem is when you are inserting, creating your users. Is it possible that you are inserting and sha1-ing a constant there? That would probably be an coding error, for example using variables in single quotes? '$var'

Comment: it gets this from the database ac137c6ae0947718332991e7cb2f50eb20b62aaa which is the sha1, but if i type in anything it always returns saying i entered ac137c6ae0947718332991e7cb2f50eb20b62aaa (don't worry the sha1 is not a secure password :) )

Comment: You have problem in code where you are **creating** or **registering** users.

Comment: You have a typo... see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. What happens when you run the code? Did you try checking what both `$password_hash` and `$row[password]` are just before the conditional?

I'm pretty sure the problem does not lie in the missing quotes, I just tested it and it works fine, but they should be there anyway.

Comment: i've added the quotes but issue is still the same.

Comment: it just always does the if statement and whether they == the same or not. And i always get the "Your password has been updated" instead of $a "passwords do not match

Comment: @John: No, that is not possible.